# I want jQuery validator to add a class to the form element's parent

Tags: jquery, validation

How do I use [jQuery validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to add/remove a classname (e.g. `validate`) on the form element's parent `<li>` so I can style everything related to that element by only setting the one classname?

The markup is

```
<li class="validate">
    <label for="product">Product of interest <abbr title="Required field">*</abbr></label>
    <input id="product" type="text" name="product" value="" placeholder="e.g. school bench" class="required" minlength="2">

    <!-- Hidden by CSS unless parent has 'validate' class -->
    <label for="product" class="description">Please name a product.</label> 
</li>
```

and the default jQuery is

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`highlight` and `unhighlight` options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) here to override where the `errorClass` (or `validClass`) gets applied:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('.validate').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest('.validate').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
  }
});
```

---

By *default*, the `errorClass` is "error" and get applied directly on the input element.  For a better illustration, this is the *default* validate functions, when you don't provide these options to `.validate()`, here's what happens:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
  errorClass: "error",
  validClass: "valid",
  highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".validate").parent().removeClass('YouCSSClass');
$(".validate").parent().addClass('YouCSSClass');
```

Also you can see some examples here http://api.jquery.com/parent/ about the add remove css classes refer to http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: No dot required in `removeClass` and `addClass`.

Comment: But how do I actually `addClass` upon `.validate()`? Something like `$("#commentForm").validate().parent().addClass("validate");` won't work.

Comment: I couldn't understand which element's parent you want to find. If you want the parent of the `<li class="validate">` you can give it an ID to identify it.

Comment: I'd like to find the `li` (which I've hardcoded to `<li class="validate">` in my question). I'm assuming there is a way to do it with the jQuery validator script itself, rather than writing an extra layer on top of it..?

Comment: Well you can set the error and valid class using the validate method like this `$("#commentForm").validate({
   validClass: ""
})  and  $("#commentForm").validate({
   errorClass: "validate"
})` Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up using Nick Craver's solution.